# CakePHP: cakeError and exit

Tags: cakephp, exit

Is it advisable to perform an `exit;` or `return;` after `throwing` a cakeError?

```
if (//successful operation)
{
    echo 'YAY';
}
else
{
    $this->cakeError('error404');
    exit; // is it necessary?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source code for ErrorHandler::error404()](http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/error-handler/#line-75), at the end it calls [`Object::_stop()`](http://api.cakephp.org/class/object#method-Object_stop) and [its source code](http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/object/#line-135) is

```
function _stop($status = 0) {
    exit($status);
}
```

In other words no, you don't have to `exit` after calling `cakeError()` because it already does so.